# Midway through my for loop the address to my array changes and gives me EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c++

The for loop on line 55 executes the first 12 run throughs fine but going from 12 to 13 it changes the memory address of my board variable from 0x00007ff7bfeff310 to 0x00007ff700000000 and throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I'm using clang on a mac and VScode.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int *dead_state (int *board, int width, int height) {
    memset(board, 0, (height * width) * sizeof(int));
    return board;
}
int *random_state (int *board, int width, int height) {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            board[(x * width) + y] = rand() % 2;
        }
    }
    return board;
}
void render_board(int *board, int width, int height) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width + 2; x++) {
        cout << "-";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)  {
        cout << "|";
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            cout << ((board[(x * width) + y]) ? "#" : " ");
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < width + 2; x++) {
        cout << "-";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int *next_board_state(int *board, int width, int height) {
    int new_board[width][height];
    int draw_board[width][height];
    dead_state(*new_board, width, height);
    dead_state(*draw_board, width, height);
    for (int x = 0; x < width * height; x++) {
        int alive = 0;
        //check right 3
        if (!(x % width == width - 1)) {
            alive += board[x + 1];
            if (!(x < width)){
                alive += board[x + 1 - width];
            }
            if (!(x >= width * height - width)) {
                alive += board[x + 1 + width];
            }
        }
        //check left 3
        if (!(x % width == 0)) {
            alive += board[x - 1];
            if (!(x < width)){
                alive += board[x - 1 - width];
            }
            if (!(x > width * height - width)) {
                alive += board[x - 1 + width];
            }
        }
        //check top
        if (!(x < width)){
            alive += board[x - width];
        }
        //check bottom
        if (!(x >= width * height - width)) {
            alive += board[x + width];
        }
        //change board states
        if (board[x] == 1) {
            if (alive == 2 || alive == 3) {
                *new_board[x] = 1;
            }
            else {
                *new_board[x] = 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (alive == 3) {
                *new_board[x] = 1;
            }
        }
        *draw_board[x] = alive;
    }
    //Assign new board to board
    for (int x = 0; x < width * height; x++) {
        board[x] = *new_board[x];
        if (x % width == 0) {
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << *draw_board[x] << " ";
    }
    return board;
}

int main () {
    int width = 5, height = 5;
    int board[width][height];
    dead_state(*board, width, height);
    random_state(*board, width, height);
    render_board(*board, width, height);
    next_board_state(*board, width, height);
    render_board(*board, width, height);
    return 0;
}
```

It's saying my post is mostly code.... And it is.  Not sure what more details I can add???

Comment: _"my post is mostly code.... And it is"_ - Good. What is your own analysis?

Comment: Is that before or after the out of bounds access? https://godbolt.org/z/WjT7b5v4Y

Comment: Your code is actually invalid. You define `board` as a variable-length array and [C++ doesn't have that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Either make sure that you use proper compile-time constants for the sizes, or use `std::vector`. Or, since you have a compile-time fixed size, use `std::array`.

Comment: And you have an array of arrays. Don't pass it around as a single "one dimension" array.

Comment: Furthermore, there are a lot of other things that just doesn't make sense, and is the reason beginners should not read about pointers or C-style arrays to early (IMO). Take for example `*new_board[x]`. Which is the same as `new_board[x][0]`. You're only using a single element of the `new_board[x]` array.

Comment: C++ is a complicated language and nearly immune to learning by guessing. I strongly recommend learning from [a reputable book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/4581301).

Comment: `board[(x * width) + y]` -- keep reading and rereading this, until you see the problem.

Comment: Who taught you to write code like this?  This is C++98, not 'modern' C++

Comment: *"on line 55"* -- I'm supposed to count lines? No thanks. Have you tried eliminating lines of code? For example, is calling `dead_state` required to reproduce the problem? If not, get rid of it. Same for the other functions. Ideally, you'd get your code to under a dozen lines and only one `for` loop (so no line counting required). See [mre] -- your goal is to demonstrate *"it changes the memory address of my board variable from 0x00007ff7bfeff310 to 0x00007ff700000000 and throws a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error."* Everything else is secondary and droppable.

Comment: *"Not sure what more details I can add???"* -- You could explain why you believe your code is indisputably correct. Line by line. This is easier if you reduce your code to a [mre] first. See also [this debugging trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @JaMiT Thank you.  Cutting things down to find minimal reproducable error makes sense and will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the need for const int sz_width = 5, sz_height = 5, Sam Varshavchik pointed out one crutial flaw in the code. You need to change your math to ((y * width) + x). You can structure a nested y, x loop to run through all of the array elements.
board[x-1] is also a problem.

```
for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
{
    int row_offset = (y * width);

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
       // un-noticeably faster by not recalculating row_offset within this loop
       
       int pos = (row_offset + x);

       board[ pos ] = abs(rand() % 2); // without abs() you might get a negative number

       // or

       // something =  board[ pos ];

       if (x == 0)          {} // left
       if (y == 0)          {} // top
       if (x == (width-1))  {} // right
       if (y == (height-1)) {} // bottom

    }
}
```